# How to make an assets folder private in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, paperclip, file-permissions

I'm using Paperclip for letting users upload photos to my app. Then, I'm saving the photos in `/public/photos`. Now, I want the photos being accessible just for some users. How can I set this permission system up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely move the photos out of `public/`, then you can use `send_file` in a controller action to display the photos instead.

I briefly skimmed over this blog post, it looked pretty good:
http://harrylove.org/2008/12/22/protected-file-downloads-with-ruby-on-rails-and-paperclip.html

Comment: The above link is dead (404).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend not saving your photos to your public folder, but rather some other folder even outside of your app directory.

Second, you can attribute your Photo model to belong_to 'some' users. Not sure what 'some' is in your description. But from then, you can in your controller, only pull photos from the Photo model that your current_user should see.